# Android AsyncTask can´t obtain GPS position

Tags: android, android-location, android-context

I´m trying to solve this problem: the coordinates sent to `onProgressUpdate()` method, are equal to 0.0. Using debugger, I´ve found out that methods `getLatitude()`,`getLongitude()` returns 0.0. The problem is, that these methods, their class was allright (I´ve used it before). Here´s the simplified code of `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStart;
MyTask objMyTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            objMyTask = new MyTask();
            objMyTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Integer> {
GPSTracker gps;
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        Double latitude, longitude;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis()-6000;
        long currentTime = t;
        int i = 0;
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
        while(i < 5)
        {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if((currentTime - t) >= 5000)
            {
                i++;
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    Double[] resultArray = new Double[2];
                    resultArray[0] = latitude;
                    resultArray[1] = longitude;
                    publishProgress(resultArray);
                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
                t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... values) {     
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude: "+values[0]+"\nLongitude"+values[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        ...
    }

}
```

}

I think that problem is in the constructor of `GPSTracker`, maybe the context is not accessible from this thread I´ve created. Here´s the constructor:

```
    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}
```

I´ve run out of ideas how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: in your GPSTracker can you print out something when you get lat lon to Log? maybe you are getting 0, 0 because lat lon were never set...?

Comment: Using debugger, I´ve found that latitude and longitude are 0, 0 inside the GPSTracker. But, like I said, this GPSTracker worked properly in the Main activity. Problem has appeared when I created AsyncTask and used GPSTracker inside.

Comment: Can you pass in the application context instead of local context to your GpsTracker?

Comment: How to do that? Sorry, I´m begineer in Android.

Comment: can you paste in your GpsTracker code? i think you should be able to get application context from regular context i.e. `regularContext.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Here´s my GPSTracker (I had pasted the whole code, though I supposed you want to see only constructor):  http://pastebin.com/dqa9ZAjN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public GPSTracker(Context context) { 
    this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext(); 
    getLocation();
}
```